# Why we can get $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> In Folland's textbook P159 Thoerem 5.8. If $\mathcal{M}$ is a closed subspace of normed vector space $\mathcal{X}$ and $x\in \mathcal{X}\setminus\mathcal{M}$, there exists $f\in \mathcal{X}^{*}$ s.t. $f(x)\neq 0$ and $f\mid M=0$.

Why we can get $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Heard of Hahn-Banach?

Comment: @SeanNemetz Yes

Comment: This question uses Hahn- Banach. Try to find a semi-norm that is zero on $M$ and non-zero on $x$.

Comment: @SeanNemetz: such a choice won't guarantee that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @MartinArgerami which choice? The semi-norm?

Comment: Yep. If you extend with a seminorm, you will get a functional that is bounded by said seminorm. You are not guaranteed that it will be continuous, unless i'm missing something.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Look up the statement of Hahn-Banach.

Comment: @SeanNemetz: I have, hundreds of times over the last 30 years. And here is an example:

Comment: Let $\mathcal X=\{x:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C:\ \text{ with finite support}\}$ with the norm $\|x\|_\infty=\max\{x_n:\ n\}$. Write $\{e_j\}$ for the canonical basis. Let $\mathcal M=\mathbb Ce_1$, $x=e_2$. Define $f(\alpha e_1+\beta e_2)=\beta$. Apply Hahn-Banach with the seminorm $p(y)=\sum_n|y_n|$. One possibility then is that Hahn-Banach gives you $\tilde f(y)=\sum_n y_n$. This is an extension of $f$ and it satisfies $|\tilde f(y)|\leq p(y)$ for all $y\in\mathcal X$. But $\tilde f$ is not bounded, since $\tilde f(\sum_{n=1}^m e_n)=m$, while $\|\sum_{n=1}^me_n\|_\infty=1$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami whoops I confused the terms "semi-norm" and "sub-linear". Forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\mathcal M+\mathbb C x$, define $f(m+\lambda x)=\lambda$. This is well-defined: if $m_1+\lambda x=m_2+\mu x$, then $(\lambda -\mu)x=m_2-m_1\in\mathcal M$; as $x\not\in\mathcal M$, this shows that $\mu=\lambda$.

Also, $\|m+\lambda x\|>0$ for all $\lambda\ne0$, as otherwise we would have $\lambda x=-m\in\mathcal M$. Then
\begin{align}
\|f\|
&=\sup\left\{\frac{|\lambda|}{\|m+\lambda x\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\ m\in\mathcal M\right\}\\
&=\sup\left\{\frac{1}{\|m/\lambda+ x\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\ m\in\mathcal M\right\}\\
&=\sup\left\{\frac{1}{\|m+ x\|}:\ m\in\mathcal M\right\}\\
&=\frac1{\inf\{\|m+x\|:\ m\in\mathcal M\}}\\
&=\frac1{\operatorname{dist}(x,\mathcal M)}.
\end{align}
So $\|f\|$ is bounded. Now we can apply Hahn-Banach to extend $f$ to a $\tilde f\in\mathcal X^*$.